# Angular $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-route

I don't know what cause this error:  [Click to see the error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.5%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:38:22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:36:49)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.e%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:36:310)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:35:23)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:35:147%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:34:428)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Lb%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js:38:146)

I'm trying to create a dynamic web application. Do I need a local-server to run this application. Currently i'm not using any local-server.

HTML:

```
<div class = "body" ng-controller = "app">
  <div class = "column2">
    <div class = "sectionName">
       <span class = "sectionName-Span">{{ page.title() }}</span>
       <div class = "container">
          <ng-view>Something went wrong</ng-view>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type=text/ng-template id=profile.html>
     I'm Lalinda Sampath Dias
  </script>
```

Controller.js:

```
var application = angular.module('mainApp', ['appServices'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/tab1', {templateUrl: 'profile.html',   controller: HomeCtrl}).
                when('/tab2', {templateUrl: 'list.html',   controller: ListCtrl}).
                otherwise({redirectTo: '/tab1'});
}]);


/* Controllers */

function MainCtrl($scope, Page) {
    console.log(Page);
    $scope.page= Page; 
}

function HomeCtrl($scope, Page) {
    Page.setTitle("Welcome");
}


function ListCtrl($scope, Page, Model) {
    Page.setTitle("Items");
    $scope.items = Model.notes();

}

function DetailCtrl($scope, Page, Model, $routeParams, $location) {
    Page.setTitle("Detail");
    var id = $scope.itemId = $routeParams.itemId;
    $scope.item = Model.get(id);
}

function SettingsCtrl($scope, Page) {
    Page.setTitle("Settings");
}

/* Services */

angular.module('appServices', [])

        .factory('Page', function($rootScope){
            var pageTitle = "Untitled";
            return {
                title:function(){
                    return pageTitle;
                },
                setTitle:function(newTitle){
                    pageTitle = newTitle;
                }
            }
        })

        .factory ('Model', function () {
            var data = [
                {id:0, title:'Doh', detail:"A dear. A female dear."},
                {id:1, title:'Re', detail:"A drop of golden sun."},
                {id:2, title:'Me', detail:"A name I call myself."},
                {id:3, title:'Fa', detail:"A long, long way to run."},
                {id:4, title:'So', detail:"A needle pulling thread."},
                {id:5, title:'La', detail:"A note to follow So."},
                {id:6, title:'Tee', detail:"A drink with jam and bread."}
            ];
            return {
                notes:function () {
                    return data;
                },
                get:function(id){
                  return data[id];
                },
                add:function (note) {
                    var currentIndex = data.length;
                    data.push({
                        id:currentIndex, title:note.title, detail:note.detail
                    });
                },
                delete:function (id) {
                    var oldNotes = data;
                    data = [];
                    angular.forEach(oldNotes, function (note) {
                        if (note.id !== id) data.push(note);
                    });
                }
            }
});
```

Edit:

```
<body ng-app = "mainApp">
        <div id = "background-div">
            <div class = "header">
                <div class = "ham-icon">
                    <img src = "images/ham-icon.png">
                </div>
                <div class = "logo">
                    <span class = "google-logo">Lalinda</span><span class = "hangouts-logo"> Sampath</span>
                </div>
                <div class = "profile-data">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "body" ng-controller = "app">
                <div class = "column1">
                    <div class = "tab1">
                        <a href = "#/tab1"><img src = "images/people-icon.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "tab2">
                        <a href = "#/tab2"><img src = "images/chat-icon.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "tab3">
                        <a href = "#/tab3"><img src = "images/phone-icon.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "tab4">
                        <a href= "#/tab4"><img src = "images/other-icon.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "column2">
                    <div class = "sectionName">
                        <span class = "sectionName-Span">{{ page.title() }}</span>
                        <div class = "container">
                            <ng-view>Something went wrong</ng-view>
                            <!--input type = "text" ng-model = "name"-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type=text/ng-template id=profile.html>
                    I'm Lalinda Sampath Dias
                </script>
                <div class = "column3">
                    <div classs = "user-greet">
                        <span class = "user-greet-span">Hi, Guest</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "det">
                        <span class = "det-span">Get started by calling or messaging a friend below</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "functional-area">
                        <div class = "video-call">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "phone-call">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "message">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Use `application.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)` syntax.

Comment: `ng-controller = "app"` where is this controller? i suppose you meant `MainCtrl`.

Comment: @Jai I declared both ng-app and ng-controller. ng-app is declared inside the body tag. <body ng-app = "mainApp">

Comment: @LalindaSampath `ng-controller !== ng-app`......!!!

Comment: @LalindaSampath see this _<div class = "body" ng-controller = "app">_

Comment: @LalindaSampath in your edit, you still have `ng-controller = "app"`. Where are you defining this controller?

Comment: @LJ.Wizard it's inside the div tag, where class name is 'body'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out an answer by my-self. When adding ngRoute as a dependency we have to load ngRoute.js file. You can download it from the internet.

Here is the Google CDN:
  [https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-route.js](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-route.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ngRoute` as depencies like this

```
var application = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute','appServices'])
```